# How to create a local backup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup

I have a linux (Ubuntu 12.04) web server and I want to create a cronjob to generate a differential backup, locally (in the same machine).

Is that possible? With differential I mean that the first time it copies everything, but the following times it only copies new files. But I also want to have many points in time, I mean at least 3 or 4 backups from which I can restore everything.

I have checked this page but there are too many different tools, and I guess each one has its own gotchas: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem#Types_of_Backup

For example, I've been told that storing .tar.gz has a limit in size.

If you have any simple suggestion, even if it's not differential, it's welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a backup disk in `/media/mydisk` and I want backup `/home/user`,
this little script will let you keep 10 history's backup, but keeping only different files more than one time.

This need that backup disk is formated with a POSIX filesystem, like Ext4, XFS or else, but **no** ntfs, **nor** fat!

```
#!/bin/bash
backRepo=/media/mydisk
backSrce=/home/user
backDest=home
backCopy=copy
backCount=9

[ -d "$backRepo/$backDest" ] || mkdir "$backRepo/$backDest"

cd $backSrce || exit 1
rsync -ax --delete --exclude '*~' --exclude '.DStore' . "$backRepo/$backDest/."

cd $backRepo
[ -d "$backCopy.$backCount" ] && rm -fR "$backCopy.$backCount"
for ((i=$backCount;i--;));do
    [ -d "$backCopy.$i" ] && mv "$backCopy.$i" "$backCopy.$((i+1))"
  done
((i++))

cp -al $backDest $backCopy.$i
```

This (`cp -al`) make hardlinks of files instead of copying it. So there are no more space used.

Rsync will *re-create* (copy on write) each modified files, so rotated backup keep old version.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I have some questions: What is .DStore? And it seems like this script will keep ~deleted files forever, is that right?

Comment: `.DStore`  and `*~` stand there for sample only. This will exclude all `.DStore` files (some Mac OS finder config cache files) and all file which name end with a tilde `~` (backup for editors like `emacs`).

Comment: Not forever, after 10 *rotation*, older will be definitively deleted.

Comment: I love this script, alternative could use datepart, as `i=$(date +%A)` instead of a simple counter, for *daily* rotation or `date +%m` for monthly, etc...

Answer (score 1):

[rsync](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/rsync.1.html) is a great tool for copying files, it can copy only the change bits in a file and it can backup the destination files before overwriting.

You can easily edit your `crontab` to run `rsync` periodically for your main backup. Then you can copy the backups for the changed files and you'll have more time points. Or you can copy the backed up data before running `rsync` to have complete image for each time point.

Unless you are going to later copy the files elsewhere, I don't think it is necessary to use `tar`.